# In which direction is the slope greatest?

Tags: calculus

You are standing on a steep hillside for which the height of the ground at a point $(x,y)$ is $f(x,y).$

If you head North you go uphill at a slope of $60^\circ$, if you go East then you go uphill at an angle of $30^\circ.$

In which direction is the slope greatest?

I know that this tells me that the directional derivative at $(0,0)$ in the direction $(0,1)$ is $\tan60$ and at $(0,0)$ in the direction $(1,0)$ is $\tan30.$ I also know that the direction of greatest change occurs in the direction of the gradient.

The solution says that the direction is $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}\left(1 , 3 \right)$$

Could someone explain why this is?

Comment: Google " curve of steepest descent."

Comment: see answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1789045